# Delete (Group) Meeting From Calendar

Tags: ipad, ical, calendar

I received an ical invite through gmail, which my IPad3 added to the calendar.  But now I'm trying to delete the event, and there is no option to do so.

I found a thread of discussion which says [the event can't be deleted if other attendees are included in the ical info](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=905359).  The only solution I've seen, also from the same thread of discussion, is to make edits on your PC and then use ITunes to synchronize the calendar.

I'm dealing with employer equipment, where installing ITunes is not an option.  In fact, attaching my IPad to the PC is also not an option.  I need to find a way to delete the meeting request from the calendar without using a PC as a life support system.

Actually my REAL problem is that the original meeting invite started at 9:30am.  Then the organizer changed the time to 9:00am.  But because the IPad can't seem to modify or delete a meeting (with other attendees) once it is created, the ical updates to my IPad are being ignored.

How do I fix this?

Now, pardon me, it is time for a rant.

This is such a ridiculous problem.  This is the year 2012, yes?  Apple is the cutting edge of tech, yes?  And neither I nor others can delete or modify a calendar event that has other attendees in it?!?!?!  My frustration is multiplied because, on an unrelated note, I'm also dealing with the common problem of apple equipment creating duplicates of music downloaded from ITunes.  The recommended solution for this latter problem, is ALSO to rely on a PC and ITunes for life-support.  Really?!

Answer (score 1):

In Settings -> Accounts -> iCloud, you can turn Calendar on, and then off. It will ask if you would like to delete all synced events. I said "yes" and they disappeared from my calendar!  In other words all of the group events with no delete option were deleted.

**NOTE: this deleted all group events.**

Answer (score 0):

You can delete these events but you have to do it in iCal on a Mac. After *fixing* the problem in iCal it will now be removed from the iPad if you are using iCloud to manage your calendar. If you are using iCloud you might check on deleting the event from iCloud.com.

Unfortunately, as you've discovered, there are limitations to deleting an invited event in iOS.

Comment: I was connected to ICloud the very moment I bought my IPad.  But on your advice, I actually visited my ICloud account today.  I was quite surprised to see that ICloud doesn't know anything about ANY of the meetings that my IPad calendar has.  I then checked google apps, which *does* know about all these meetings.  Even so, ICloud does know about my IPad "reminders."  So it is not as if ICloud is entirely disconnected.  When I check my ICloud settings on the IPad, it shows all apps being synced, except for Mail (I have gmail setup) and Notes.  So why no sync on the calendar?

Comment: Did deleting the event in Google Apps fix the problem? ::fingers crossed:: I'm at a loss to see why the event, which you added to your iPad calendar, doesn't seem to be part of your iCloud calendar. Or did you add the event to your Google calendar. If yes, then you should be able to add your Google calendar as a subscribed calendar in iPad calendar. It should then update as you update and edit your Google calendar.

Comment: Genius bar at Apple store got involved.  ICal info was being seen only by google calendar.  The tech tried to get ICloud involved by creating a new Exchange-based gmail account (I did not know google operated MS Exchange servers!).  While cool, it didn't actually cause google calendar events to sync with ICloud.  However, the errant calendar events got "shaken out" of the system, and my IPad calendar now looks correct.  I will take up the issue of no ICal-ICloud syncing later.